# Converting multiple rows to clumns

Tags: mysql, database

I want to change my rows to a column. This is what I have now:

```
NAME      | YEAR | INCOME  | EXPENSE
COMPANY-1 | 2017 | €30000  | €15000
COMPANY-1 | 2016 | €50000  | €10000
COMPANY-2 | 2017 | €20000  | €5000
COMPANY-2 | 2016 | €80000  | €95000
```

And this is what I want:

```
NAME      | INCOME_2017  | EXPENSE_2017 | INCOME_2016  | EXPENSE_2016
COMPANY-1 | €30000       | €15000       | €50000       | €10000
COMPANY-2 | €20000       | €5000        | €80000       | €95000
```

Has someone an idea how i can do this? I have copied a lot of PIVOT scripts. But that didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this sql to get desired result.

1) use CASE for getting desired column.

2) Use max condition to get max value.

```
SELECT  `name` ,
 MAX( CASE WHEN  `year` =2017 THEN  `income` ELSE 0 END ) AS INCOME_2017,
 MAX( CASE WHEN  `year` =2017 THEN  `expense` ELSE 0 END ) AS EXPENSE_2017,
 MAX( CASE WHEN  `year` =2016 THEN  `income` ELSE 0 END ) AS INCOME_2016,
 MAX( CASE WHEN  `year` =2016  THEN  `expense` ELSE 0 END ) AS EXPENSE_2016
 FROM  `test_data` GROUP BY  `name`
```